# Referencing results from a SPARQL query in a subsequent SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf

We would like to use SPARQL in the following scenario:

1. Execute SPARQL query, e.g.

```
    PREFIX brick: https://brickschema.org/schema/1.1/Brick# 
    SELECT ?ahu WHERE { ?ahu rdf:type brick:AHU }
```

2. Iterate over SPARQL query results and filter the results based on data from another source than RDF database, e.g. "filter out any `ahu` that do not have valid metadata a SQL database"
3. Execute another SPARQL query for each filtered result in the previous step, e.g.

```
    PREFIX brick:  https://brickschema.org/schema/1.1/Brick#
    SELECT ?myZone WHERE { 
    ?myZone rdf:type brick:HVAC_Zone . 
    "a particular ahu from previous steps" brick:feeds ?myZone}
```

Both SPARQL queries cannot be expressed as one SPARQL query since interaction with another data source is needed. How shall we design query in step 3 such that it "points" to the particular triplet (or SPARQL query result)?

Comment: can you give an example please? I mean, in step 3 you obviously need something the identifies the entities for which you want to get additional information. I do not understand why those can't be URIs

Comment: I added a particular example to the original question.

Comment: thanks. So why can't you simply use the `?ahu` entities in step 3 ? Also, both triple patterns are not connected, i.e. there is no shared variable as far as I can see. This is bad and will lead to the cartesian product of both binding sets

Comment: What do you mean by "use `?ahu` entities"?


There was no link between zone and ahu, that was a mistake. I fixed that in the example.

Comment: You got a list of `?ahu` bindings from your first query, don't you? Those are most likely just URIs. Why can't you use those URIs in the other query then? Like `PREFIX brick:  <https://brickschema.org/schema/1.1/Brick#>
    SELECT ?myZone WHERE { VALUES ?ahu {<AHU_URI_1> <AHU_URI_2> ... }
    ?myZone rdf:type brick:HVAC_Zone . 
    ?ahu  brick:feeds ?myZone}` - is this not possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. It is exactly what I was looking for. I just got lost in the prefixes and URI definitions. Thank you!